# System is not able to go in runlevel 0

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, init, runlevel

I have a basic question if we issue a power-off to a device does it goes in runlevel 0 ?

As far as I understand when a power-off is issued runlevel changes from 3 to 0 accordingly the `/etc/init.d/halt` script gets called.

This halt file is executed by init when it goes into runlevel 0 (halt) or runlevel 6 (reboot). It kills all processes, unmounts file systems and then either halts or reboots.

In my case the blade gets powered off without executing the halt script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with `packageMapping.list` we had failed to pacakge a rpm which had a binary named `hpmcmd` which was responsible to issue a reset as this binary was missing so the reset command failed resulting system going for halt.